# Get success status for a device which uninstalled the app in JavaPNS

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am testing the situation in which a device has already uninstalled the app.

When I tried to push a notification via JavaPNS to the iPhone which uninstalled the app, I got success, but in the device no message was received.

**Why does JavaPNS return success even though the related app is no longer installed on the device?
How can I solve this ?**

```
        for (PushedNotification notification : notifications) {
            if (notification.isSuccessful()) {
                //success
            } else {
                iPhoneFailedPushed += 1;
                String deviceId = notification.getDevice() != null ? notification.getDevice().getDeviceId() : "";
                String exception = notification.getException() != null ? notification.getException().getMessage() : "";
                /* Add code here to remove invalidToken from database */
                if (notification.getResponse() != null)
                {
                    //show error code
                }
                else
                {
                    //show exception                
                }
                //log fail token
            }
        }
```

Comment: i dont know JAVAPNS but i suggest success means the notification got delivered to the Apple server. The Apple-Server can not always decide synchronous if it will be able to deliver the notification to the Device, so you will get a success in many cases the notification did not actualy reach the Device. There should be a asynchronous Feedback implementation in JAVAPNS to remove invalid Devices.

Comment: imm... but due to their example, it seem like we can immediately knows whether it is invalid token or not if notification.isSuccessful() is false case. http://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/ManagingPushErrors

Comment: your token was valid at some time and so you get a success response until the token is removed from the Apple-Server, and this may take some time. Look at the [FeedbackService](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/FeedbackService) the Token should appear there at some point.

Comment: imm.. what you suggest makes sense. To retrieve it from apple FeedBackService. But I wonder why it takes too long to get the message via Error-response packets as I uninstall the app since morning (around 6 hr ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never get the error response packets in this case, since this is a valid device token (uninstalling the app doesn't change that). The only way to detect that the app was uninstalled is to use the feedback service.

From the APNS documentation :

> If a provider attempts to deliver a push notification to an
>   application, but the application no longer exists on the device, the
>   device reports that fact to Apple Push Notification Service. This
>   situation often happens when the user has uninstalled the application.
>   If a device reports failed-delivery attempts for an application, APNs
>   needs some way to inform the provider so that it can refrain from
>   sending notifications to that device. Doing this reduces unnecessary
>   message overhead and improves overall system performance.
>
> For this purpose Apple Push Notification Service includes a feedback
>   service that APNs continually updates with a per-application list of
>   devices for which there were failed-delivery attempts. The devices are
>   identified by device tokens encoded in binary format. Providers should
>   periodically query the feedback service to get the list of device
>   tokens for their applications, each of which is identified by its
>   topic. Then, after verifying that the application hasn’t recently been
>   re-registered on the identified devices, a provider should stop
>   sending notifications to these devices.